# What is the best way to edit a file, then commit, using "VERSIONS"?

Tags: svn, macos, version

I have been able to get the remote files on a mac, but I am having trouble EDITING, then seeing how to "commit" back to the remote server...

I was able to follow tortoise quite intuitively but do not see where to check out files and then edit, then check back in ...

Comment: Do you mean Versions, available here?: http://versionsapp.com/